# Kohana 3: How to route subdirectories in application/classes/controller

Tags: php, kohana

I'm quite new to Kohana and was wondering what the best way was of organising a lot of files in the application/classes/controller directory.

My current structure is:

```
-application
--classes
---controller
----page
-----test.php
```

And I want to call the page from a url without it needing the page or optionally the name of any other subdirectory:

```
www.website.com/test/
```

My controller class starts:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

/**
* Test
* 
* @package Test
* @category Page
* @author 
* 
*/
class Controller_Page_Test extends Controller_Template {

        // Default
        public function action_index() {
            // Template vars
    }

}
```

What do I need to do to avoid the 404 error it is throwing? I assume I need to set up a route in bootstrap.php but I don't really get what to do to allow the pages to activate from within subdirectories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `directory` param in Routes:

```
Route::set('with_dir', 
           'test(/<action>(/<id>))', 
           )
    ->defaults(array(
          'directory'  => 'page',
          'controller' => 'test',
    ));
```

You can use regex for controller list. For example, you have Controller_Test and Controller_Foo in a page directory. Here is a route for it:

```
Route::set('with_dir', 
           '<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', 
           array(
               'controller'  => '(test|foo)',
           ))
    ->defaults(array(
          'directory'  => 'page',
          'controller' => 'test',
    ));
```

Comment: This brings me much closer, thank you. :)
The only question I have is how can you make the directory name optional?
In your example the directory has to be 'page'.

Comment: You can set `<directory>` value in the URI (like `<controller>` or `<action>`), but this way your URIs will be larger, that simple `/test/`. Also, in 3.1 (and with PHPv5.3) you can use [lambda routes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic) with a lot of features for setting route params.